# Does an index point to the block the record is stored in?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I've been studying about indexes in databases. However, I've not seen anything specifically referencing what the index actually points to.

**Does an index point to the block that the record is stored in, or, does it point directly to the record in a block?**

Thanks very much,

Chris.

Comment: I hope this information will be helpful to you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179613(v=sql.105).aspx